# Escape question mark characters as placeholders for MySQL query in NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have the following query that I'm using in the query function (https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values) :

```
database.query("UPDATE Project SET Content = 'Hello ?' WHERE Id = ?", [id], function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.json({ status: 'FAIL QUERY' });
        } else {
            res.json({ status: 'SUCCESS' });
        }
    });
```

I have an error because it is replacing the question mark on "'Hello ?'" and "WHERE Id = ?" and he only have one attribute : [id].
How to avoid this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have various options:

```
database.query("UPDATE Project SET Content = ? WHERE Id = ?", [ 'Hello ?', id], function(err, rows, fields) { ... })
```

Or:

```
database.query("UPDATE Project SET Content = 'Hello ?' WHERE Id =" + mysql.escape(id), function(err, rows, fields) { ... });
```

Answer (score 3):

I would report this as a bug to that project. They should not replace the `?` characters when those character appear:

- Inside string literals, as in your example.
- Inside delimited identifiers. It's uncommon, but legal SQL, to use punctuation symbols as part of a table name or column name.
- Inside comments.

If that Node.js project is replacing the `?` regardless of context, then this is an unacceptable bug.

I would stop using that package until they fix the bug.

Comment: The user is warned about this behaviour (and it's also explained, though not in so many words, that the offered functionality is more for convenience than an official implementation of prepared statements). There are other options available.

Comment: @robertklep, Regardless of whether the behavior is documented, it's wrong. I thought Node.js was supposed to be so hot and so much better than PHP—but PDO does parse for parameters correctly. Sorry, I'm not accepting excuses for this bug. This is really disappointing, especially for a package that has been around for several years.

Comment: What does PHP have to do with this? Also, if you feel so strongly about it, feel free to post a bug report: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues Also, this isn't the only MySQL library for Node, [`mysql2`](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2#using-prepared-statements) supports proper prepared statements.

Comment: PHP is just an example of another implementation that parses placeholders better. I mention it just to show that it can be done. That's good to hear about mysql2 that there's an alternative that people can use until mysqljs is fixed. Thanks, I may log a bug, though I have no horse in the game since I don't use Node.js.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all your answer ! I learned a lot.
The robertklep answer using (mysql.escape(id)) worked for me.

However I found another way that I'm sharing with you for adding multiple parameters to the query :

You can create a JSON called queryJSON and adding to it key - value. Ex : `queryJSON = {Content: 'Hello ?', Address: '742 Evergreen Terrace'}`. And then :

```
database.query("UPDATE Offer SET ? WHERE Id = ?", [queryJSON, id], function(err, rows, fields) {
```

This is usefull for my put request for adding one or more paramters to the request.

Answer (score 0):

Prepared statements will replace each instance of `?`, in order, with the elements in the passed array, also in order. You will need to use a different placeholder character if you want to keep it as a placeholder, or have 2 elements in the array, the first being what the `?` after `Hello` will be replaced with (bear in mind that it will also put single quotes around that element) and the second one for `Id = ?`

Answer (score 0):

**Preventing SQL injections**

Escape question mark characters as placeholders for MySQL query in NodeJS is used to prevent SQL injections (Example 1). You can use **escape** function to do the same (Example 2).

To prevent SQL injections, you should use **escape** function the values when query values are variables provided by the user.

Example 1: Escape query values by using the **placeholder ?** method

```
var adr = 'Mountain 21';
var sql = 'SELECT * FROM customers WHERE address = ?';
con.query(sql, [adr], function (err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(result);
});
```

Example 2: Here we used **escape** function to avoid **SQL injections**

```
var adr = 'Mountain 21';
var sql = 'SELECT * FROM customers WHERE address = ' + mysql.escape(adr);
con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(result);
});
```

[More details](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql_where.asp)